# Match from beginning to word as long as there are no . in between: Convert grep -Po command to sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep

I have made the following command to be able to match the string from the beginning of the line until the first occurrence of ".enabled" as long as there are no "." in between.

`grep -Po '^\K[\w-]*?(?=\.enabled)'`

input:

```
a-b-c.a.enabled.xxx.xx
a-b-c.a.b.enabled.xxx.xx
a-b-c.enabled.xxx.xx
```

output:

```
a-b-c
```

It runs properly on my local env with grep v3.1 but on Busybox v1.28.4 it says "**grep: unrecognized option: P**"

For that reason, I would like to convert this command to sed. Any input would be really helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
awk -F'.' '$2 == "enabled"{print $1}' file
sed -n 's/^\([^.]*\)\.enabled.*/\1/p' file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/FrkjDG).

*Details*:

 *awk*:

- `-F'.'` - the field separator is set to a `.`
- `$2 == "enabled"` - if Group 2 value is `enabled`, then
- `{print $1}` - print Field 1 value
  *sed*:
- `-n` - suppresses default line output in the `sed` command
- `s/^\([^.]*\)\.enabled.*/\1/p` - finds any zero or more chars other than `.` at the start of string (placing them into Group 1, `\1`), then a `.enabled` and then the rest of the string and replaces with the Group 1 value, and `p`rints the resulting value.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, you could try following.

```
awk -F'\\.enabled' '$1~/^[-_[:alnum:]]+$/{print $1}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simply making field separator as `.enabled` for all the lines here. Then in main program checking condition if 1st field is having `-`-`or`_` or alphanumeric then print 1st field here.

Comment: I have extra characters after ".enabled" , I will edit the question to clarify and I only want to extract before ".enabled"

Comment: @enio, Sure, I had edited solution now, please check it once if that helps you?

Answer (score 2):

You may use this equivalent `sed` of your `grep -P` command:

```sh
sed -nE 's/^([-_[:alnum:]]+)\.enabled.*/\1/p' file

a-b-c
```

**Details:**

- `-n`: Suppress notmal output
- `-E`: Enables extended regex mode
- `([-_[:alnum:]]+)`: `-_[:alnum:]]`is equivalent of `[-\w]` or `[-_a-zA-Z0-9]`. It matches 1+ of these characters and captures them in group #1
- `\.enabled.*`: matches `.enabled` followed by 0 or more of any string
- `\1`: is replacement string that put value captured in capture group #1 back in replacement